# Line Colours Graphics3D - Plotting Photon Paths

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, color

### The Problem

I want to be able to change the colour of parts of lines in Graphics 3D. I don't know a good way.

Below is how I've got so far and a diagram of I want. I.e. I want to be able to control the colour of the line segments from data. The integer value between 400-700nm should be the colour. (these can be simplified if required)

[image]

[image]

Example Data & Plotting Code

```
photonlives = {{{"Start", {8.908399661129824`, 9.633102260661355`, 5}, 407}, {"Emission", {8.908399661129824`, 9.633102260661355`, 2.496926971098662`},407}, {"Left", {11.087670534918876`, 8.219492769746015`, 3.432302819553219`},300}}, {{"Start", {1.9856853654615514`, 6.848440992081457`, 5},594}, {"Emission", {1.9856853654615514`, 6.848440992081457`, 2.6228644835985957`},594}, {"Left", {2.521141087121206`, 5.323725115908513`, 3.012965011108447`},300}}, {{"Start", {5.382360511331741`, 4.408513016017577`, 5},524}, {"Emission", {5.382360511331741`, 4.408513016017577`, 2.0636538349485796`},524}, {"Emission", {5.9510903463320135`, 6.191633074632532`, 1.365916379273969`},300}, {"Emission", {4.141206920229977`, 5.773532803626935`, 1.1486020989253132`},300}, {"Absorbed", {4.731487780277531`, 3.5166296163565747`, 0.9018958429272086`},300}}, {{"Start", {5.7064477543041985`, 8.960806835584687`, 5},499}, {"Absorbed", {5.7064477543041985`, 8.960806835584687`, 2.6904886316076606`},499}}, {{"Start", {8.290340872256385`, 2.9730634116539956`, 5},409}, {"Reflection", {8.290340872256385`, 2.9730634116539956`, 3}, 409}, {"Left", {9.25283380442492`, 0.9128219903837054`, 5},409}}, {{"Start", {7.109178085659753`, 1.4811083443707118`, 5},537}, {"Emission", {7.109178085659753`, 1.4811083443707118`, 2.3677442987465627`},537}, {"Left", {5.423234919050124`, -0.4911618443561132`, 1.6554688841042937`},300}}, {{"Start", {3.6761465640204927`, 9.226495379895743`, 5},606}, {"Reflection", {3.6761465640204927`, 9.226495379895743`, 3}, 606}, {"Left", {0.5167471944485746`, 4.671778417759236`, 5}, 606}}, {{"Start", {4.383581619316823`, 2.2526259659816184`, 5},401}, {"Reflection", {4.383581619316823`, 2.2526259659816184`, 3}, 401}, {"Left", {9.404425720369971`, 4.8467050372875775`, 5},  401}}, {{"Start", {1.9099177632828113`, 8.593414202432443`, 5},560}, {"Emission", {1.9099177632828113`, 8.593414202432443`, 2.6092504664365213`},560}, {"Emission", {2.7699445700893683`, 7.423796219035573`, 2.624089283248043`},300}, {"Left", {0.5502206495992263`, 5.467835704409955`, 3.3137618986450716`},300}}, {{"Start", {3.6746266719085408`, 0.28929707744424604`, 5}, 592}, {"Emission", {3.6746266719085408`, 0.28929707744424604`, 2.4109510252927`},592}, {"Emission", {1.8174965321127263`, 2.541633357705031`, 2.7993512767850586`},300}, {"Absorbed", {2.371991341538078`, 0.5034533844835565`, 2.686939720078675`}, 300}}};

Graphics3D[{Line[photonlives[[All, All, 2]]], {Opacity[0.2], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {10, 10, 3}]}}]
```

I'm really at a lost end - any idea would be helpful.

---

### Background

I have a program which tracks what photons are doing in a box filled with plastic. It contains a dye which will absorb and re-emit the light at a new colour/frequency. The "frequency in nm" should correspond to a colour

It produces output which gives a list for each photon which describes the life of the photon. It looks like.

```
{{"Process 1"}, {"x","y","z"}, {"frequency in nm"}, {"Process 2"}, {"x","y","z"}, {"frequency in nm"}, ... }
```

An example is

```
{{"Start", {8.9, 9.6, 5}, 407}, {"Emission", {8.9, 9.6, 2.5}, 407}, {"Left", {11.0, 8.2, 3.4}, 300}}
```

Each photon starts which a location with *Start*. Then, there are 4 processes available - *reflection* (which means the photon doesn't get into the box), *absorption* (which kills the photon in the box), *emission* (which means the frequency of the photon is changed) and *left* (which means the photon has left the interesting area).

I have attached the whole code which generates the above figure, in case there might be a better way of dealing with the data.

```
(* This number of times we track the photon *) 
numberofphotons = 1000; 
(*array to track the photons *) 
photonlives = ConstantArray[0, numberofphotons];

(* the size of our box *) 
xbox = 10; 
ybox = 10; 
zbox = 3; 

dyefreq = 300;

For[i = 1, i <= numberofphotons, i++, 

 Photonabsorbedflag = 0; 
 (* Photons begin above the box in a random location*) 
 x = RandomReal[]*xbox; 
 y = RandomReal[]*ybox;
 z = 5; 

 (* Pick the colour of the photons *) 
 lamda = RandomInteger[{400, 700}];

 (* Record where the photon begins *) 
 photonlives[[i]] = {{"Start", {x, y, z}, lamda}};


 (* Reflection *) 
 If[ RandomReal[] < 0.4,  

  (* Find location of reflection *) 
  photonlives[[i]] = 
   Append[photonlives[[i]] , {"Reflection", {x, y, 3}, lamda}];

  (* Assume the photons are scattered randomly *) 
  photonlives[[i]] = 
   Append[photonlives[[i]] , {"Left", {RandomReal[]*xbox, 
      RandomReal[]*ybox, 5}, lamda}];

  (* Begin next photon *) 
  Continue[]
  ];


 (* ------- In the Plastic Block -------*) 


 pathlengthz = RandomReal[]* zbox/3; 
  z = 3 - pathlengthz;

 While[ x > 0 && x < xbox && y > 0 && y < ybox && z > 0 && z < zbox, 

  (* Photon absorbed by substrate and just dies *) 

  If[RandomReal[] < 0.2,

   photonlives[[i]] = 
    Append[photonlives[[i]] , {"Absorbed", {x, y, z}, lamda}];
   Photonabsorbedflag = 1; 
   (*breaks while loop*) 
   Break[];

   ];

  (* Photon absorbed by dye and remitted at new freq *)

  If[RandomReal[] < 0.4,

   photonlives[[i]] = 
    Append[photonlives[[i]] , {"Emission", {x, y, z}, lamda}];

   pathlengthx = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]* xbox/3;
   pathlengthy = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]* ybox/3;
   pathlengthz = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]* zbox/3;

   x = x + pathlengthx;
   y = y + pathlengthy;
   z = z + pathlengthz;

   lamda = dyefreq; 
   (*breaks while loop*) 
   ];

  ];

 If[Photonabsorbedflag == 0, 
  photonlives[[i]] = 
   Append[photonlives[[i]] , {"Left", {x, y, z}, lamda}]

  ];
 ]
Graphics3D[{Line[photonlives[[All, All, 2]]], {Opacity[0.2], 
   Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {xbox, ybox, zbox}]}}]
```

Comment: This kind of work can be done easily in *Optica* (http://www.opticasoftware.com).

Comment: I agree - but it seems expensive ($2000!) method just to add colour =P . I have no need for fancy ray tracing software, I just want to add some colour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how important it is that each line segment has a constant color, but you could give each point a `VertexColor`. This is as simple as

```
colorLine[entry_] := With[{pts = Transpose[entry][[2 ;;]]},
  Tube[pts[[1]], VertexColors -> (ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"] /@ pts[[2]])]
];
Graphics3D[colorLine /@ photonlives]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Edit

```
colorLine[entry_] := {ColorData["VisibleSpectrum", Last[#3]], Tube[#2]} & @@@ 
  (Transpose[#] & /@ Partition[entry, 2, 1])
Graphics3D[colorLine /@ photonlives]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I would really appreciate if the line segment could have a constant colour - but maybe that simple isn't an option.

Comment: @Tomi Your data-structure has a color connected the every *point*. A line is a connection between two points that might have a different color. How do you plan to determine the color for the line?

Comment: The line *to* the point should be the colour described in each entry in the dataset. i.e. in the example {{"Start", {8.9, 9.6, 5}, 407}, {"Emission", {8.9, 9.6, 2.5}, 407}, {"Left", {11.0, 8.2, 3.4}, 300}}, the first line segment should be the 407 colour, then the second line segment the 300 colour.